# How to store UserData in complex object in a Bot

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to store an object in the UserData of a Bot.

First of all I have the following class:

```
public class PersonalData 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; } 
}
```

In my Luis Class I need a variable of type PersonalData.

```
public class Luis : LuisDialog<object> 
{
    PersonalData personalData;
```

This already leads to the problem that the debugger never goes into any of my intents. Whats wrong with that?

Now, if I create an object of PersonalData in an intent like this:

```
PersonalData personalData = new PersonalData();
```

it will be created successfully.
But when I want to assign a value to my object

```
if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.personalData, out personalData)) 
{
        personalData.Name = userName;
        context.UserData.SetValue(ContextConstants.personalData, personalData.Name);
}
```

As soon as the program tries to set the `personalData.Name` to `userName` I get a `NullReferenceException` and my `PersonalData` object is null.
I've double checked that userName is not empty.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `UserData`, why you need to have a variable in your dialog?

If you want to have a variable, your `PersonalData` must be serializable, so you will need to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to the class.

But instead of saving a variable in the dialog, you should always access to the `PersonalData` object you will be saving in your `UserData` bag.

Now, when you are setting the value, instead of saving the whole object, you are just saving the name, so when you are retrieving the personal data from the `UserData` bag, you are retrieving the name, not the object, that's why you are getting a `NullReferenceException`, because `personalData.Name` doesn't exists.

I think the code should be:

```
if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.personalData, out personalData)) 
{
        personalData.Name = userName;
        context.UserData.SetValue(ContextConstants.personalData, personalData);
}
```

To learn more about state, you can also see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State) sample.

Comment: I had to initialize my PersonalData object after the IF statement like this: personalData = new PersonalData(); and then it worked just fine with your solution.

Comment: I figured out, that if the the function "TryGetValue" fails, the out value is set to null. That is why one has to initialize the object variable first, and then set any values.